# How to change state in React Native on componentDidMount?

Tags: react-native

I have following warning: Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the Home component.

```
export default class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loaded: false,
      failed: false
    };
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    Actions.auth();
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    Actions.loadUser.completed.listen(this.onLoadUserCompleted.bind(this));
    Actions.goHome.listen(this.onGoHome.bind(this));
    Actions.logout.listen(this.onLogout.bind(this));
  }
  onLoadUserCompleted(user) {
    let currentUser = DataStore.getCurrentUser();
    this.setState ({ loaded: true }); // <=============
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

componentDidMount() can change the state with setState. We have lots of those things in our code, see the example below. I guess that another call of setState() will cause this warning, maybe in another view/component? (or that your component gets unmounted unexpectedly for some reason)

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      runAfterInteractions: false,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
      this.setState({
        runAfterInteractions: true,
      });
    });
  }

  render() {

    if(!this.state.runAfterInteractions) return null;
    ....
```